# How do I multiply a matrix by a scalar only for given indices in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to find an efficient way to multiply specific values within a matrix for a given scalar. Let's see a quick example.

Given a matrix M of values between 1 and 10 like so:

[image]

I want to multiply every cell that has value smaller than 3, by 2. Now I know I can find the coordinates of all items that have value 1 in tensorflow with `tf.where(M < 3)` but I am struggling to find a good scalable solution to attain what I want. The transformation should be something like this:

[image]

How can I leverage this info to multiply only the cells at the given coordinates by 2 ?

Keep in mind that my matrices might be mich bigger than 3x3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out how to do this in tensorflow without having to do any transformation from numpy to tensorflow and vice-versa.

```
my_matrix = tf.constant([[1, 5, 8], [2, 2, 2], [9, 7, 6]])
result = tf.where(
    tf.less(my_matrix, tf.constant(3)),
    tf.scalar_mul(2, my_matrix),
    my_matrix
)
```

@Josh answer helped me look into the right direction

Answer (score 2):

```
M = np.array([[1, 5, 8],[2, 2, 2], [9, 7, 6]])
M[M==1] = 2
print(M)

array([[2, 5, 8],
       [2, 2, 2],
       [9, 7, 6]])
```

Comment: That would work but it's not exactly what I wanted, you are assigning the value 2 to all elements that are 1, but I want to multiply those values by 2. Now using 1 was just an example, it could be 5, it could be 8. I won't know what that is. I'm gonna rephrase my question to make it more clear. Thanks for the response though!

Comment: I guess it would be `M[M < 3] *= 2` given the updated question.

Comment: Yeah, that should work. The format is just `<Matrix>[<Conditional to find in matrix>] = <New value operation>`

Comment: I guess that works actually, the only thing is that I have to convert it from a tensor to a numpy array, do this math and then back to tensor. Do you think there's a way to stay within the tensorflow domain ?